# PHP imap_mail_move: what is the correct ID from imap_header to use?

Tags: php, imap

So here is an `imap_header` dump...

```
$header = imap_header($mbox,$cms->page2);
```

> stdClass Object (
>       [date] => Tue, 11 Jun 2013 19:12:28 -0700
>       [Date] => Tue, 11 Jun 2013 19:12:28 -0700
>       [subject] => Account on darnhippies.org Forum locked out
>       [Subject] => Account on darnhippies.org Forum locked out
>       [message_id] => <201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org>
>       [toaddress] => webmaster@example.com
>       [to] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => stdClass Object
>                   (
>                       [mailbox] => webmaster
>                       [host] => example.com
>                   )
>
> ```
>     )
>
> [fromaddress] => "darnhippies.org Forum" <webmaster@darnhippies.org>
> [from] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [personal] => darnhippies.org Forum
>                 [mailbox] => webmaster
>                 [host] => darnhippies.org
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [reply_toaddress] => "darnhippies.org Forum" <webmaster@darnhippies.org>
> [reply_to] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [personal] => darnhippies.org Forum
>                 [mailbox] => webmaster
>                 [host] => darnhippies.org
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [senderaddress] => "darnhippies.org Forum" <webmaster@darnhippies.org>
> [sender] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => stdClass Object
>             (
>                 [personal] => darnhippies.org Forum
>                 [mailbox] => webmaster
>                 [host] => darnhippies.org
>             )
>
>     )
>
> [Recent] =>  
> [Unseen] =>  
> [Flagged] =>  
> [Answered] =>  
> [Deleted] =>  
> [Draft] =>  
> [Msgno] =>   22
> [MailDate] => 11-Jun-2013 20:12:29 -0600
> [Size] => 2008
> [udate] => 1371003149
> ```

I've been trying to move by using `$header->Msgno` as the message id, I presume since no messages have moved that this is not the correct id.

So do I use (in this example) `$header->message_id` as the id of the message to move?

I tried...

```
$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'<201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org>','Inbox.Trash');

$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org','Inbox.Trash');

$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'<201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org>','Inbox.Trash',CP_UID);

$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org','Inbox.Trash',CP_UID);

$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'<201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org>','Inbox.Trash','CP_UID');

$result1 = imap_mail_move($mbox,'201306120228.417bc449d097@www.darnhippies.org','Inbox.Trash','CP_UID');
```

I've also tried using the full inbox name including the server address just because.

I get the following errors about 90% of the time...

```
$boxes = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{mail.example.com}", "*");
print_r($boxes);
```

> Error: Array (
>       [0] => IMAP protocol error: Error in IMAP command COPY: Invalid messageset
>       [1] => Error in IMAP command COPY: Invalid messageset )

---

So how do I find the correct message id?

What is an UID?

I'm aware I can pass a comma-separated list of id's, I'm just trying to move a single message first.

Answer (score 1):

John, you should use the message's `UID` to ensure that you're referencing the correct email. The msgno is a sequence number that changes as emails are added and removed from the mailbox. You get a message's `UID` in php (using the php imap library) with:

`$uid = imap_uid(*mailbox stream handle*, *msgno*);`

the resultant $uid is unique within the mailbox forever.

When you use the UID to move/read/whatever a message, you need to add an option to the parameters passed to the relevant function, to indicate you're using a UID rather than msgno e.g.:

`$body = imap_fetchbody(*stream handle*, $uid, *mime-type*, FT_UID);`

`FT_UID` is a constant that tells the imap library that the second parameter is a `UID` not `msgno`.

The php.net documentation is quite good when it comes to the imap library and well worth a read.

Incidently, the message_id should be unique for all emails globally if the sender is meeting relevant RFC's

Comment: Something to note if you stumble across this question/answer while referencing a different IMAP command: the flag is slightly different for each. For example, on map_move() it is 'CP_UID' instead so make sure to check each function's page.

Answer (score 0):

In IMAP, every message has two identifiers: the message sequence number (which I assume is msgNo in PHP), and the unique ID (UID).  The message sequence number can change as messages are added and removed from the mailbox, but the UID is permanent for the life of the message*.

The string you are using is a "Message-Id" from the Message-Id header from the email, which can not be used to move messages (for one, it's not necessarily unique).  If you have the UID, You should be able to use imap_mail_move with the UID modifier flag to move the message.

(I'm not familiar with the PHP API, but maybe you can pass the UID modifier flag to message_header to get UIDs there too, in your result set.)

*: As long as the UIDVALIDITY of the folder does not change, which it should not on well-behaved servers, as long as the folder is not deleted and recreated with the same name.

Comment: This hasn't helped me at all.